# Flutter lifecycle: reading data from SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

When and where should I do such actions, as reading data from `SharedPreferences`?

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.getStringList('_wordsList');
```

I want to read data on initial load.

Assume we have:

1) `class WordsList extends StatefulWidget`

2) `class WordsListState extends State<WordsList>`

Should I do it in (1) constructor, or in (1) createState method, or in the correspond methods in (2), or other option?

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs; // member variable.
```

Initialise it in `initState()`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // do it like this
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    prefs = prefs;
    setState(() {});
  });
}
```

And whenever you need the value from this prefs, all you need to do is use

```
prefs.getX("key");
```

Comment: Shouldn't I wait for SharedPreferences to load? In that case is initState a good place to block execution?

Comment: We are not blocking anything in `initState` as we didn't use `async/await`, however it is just a matter of milliseconds, when you have your instance ready for use. Do you want to fetch a value in `build()` method?

Comment: Yes, I want it in build method, and I want to avoid extra checks like "value ? value.key : null"

Comment: So for that, you have 2 options, you either use `FutureBuilder` or make your `main` method `async` and `await` in it to fetch the `SharedPreference` instance.

Comment: `FutureBuilder` sounds very good. I'll check it and come back.